# Why is LastPass showing a number under its icon (Chrome)

Tags: lastpass

My LastPass symbol for some reason has a number under it. This started today, and I'm not sure why it's there. Any ideas?

[image: Lastpass number]

Comment: https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?t=83155&p=276169 may help

Comment: Yes, I actually discovered this later and totally forgot that I had made this question. Feel free to put that as your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?t=83155&p=276169) forum post. It appears this was a minor bug in one of the versions of Lastpass. This issue has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: That link doesn't answer the question of "what is the meaning of the number on the icon?"

Answer (score 1):

It indicates the number of passwords you have for the site you are visiting.
see https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/what-does-the-number-on-the-lastpass-field-icon-